# OrientDB How to get (grouped) relational data as JSON instead of objects

Tags: json, group-by, match, orientdb, graph-databases

I'm pretty new to OrientDB and tried to find an answer online or in the docs but can not find it.

If i'm writing a MATCH query and returning grouped results I can only get the Id's of the records.

My Query:

```
MATCH {class: SKU, as: sku}-categorizedIn->{class:Category, as: subcat}<-hasSubcategory-{class: Category, as: cat, where: (name='Drinks')}
RETURN subcat.name, CONCAT(sku)
GROUP BY subcat.name
```

This returns something like:
 subcat.name

```
concat    |   (sku, ',')
--------------------------------
Wine      |   #46:0,#50:0,#49:0
Beer      |   #48:0,#47:0,#46:1
```

How can i get a combined result that contains all the data like:

```
concat    |   (sku, ',')
--------------------------------
Wine      |   [{_id: "#46:0", name: "Merlot" },{_id: "#50:0", name: "Pinot" },{_id: "#49:0", name: "Shiraz" }]
Beer      |   [{_id: "#48:0", name: "Budweiser light" },{_id: "#47:0", name: "Stella Artroix" },{_id: "#46:1", name: "Heineken" }]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.toJSON()` method to get all the data you need:

Syntax: `<value>.toJSON([<format>])`

Source: [SQL Methods > .toJSON()](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Methods.html#tojson)

Comment: Hi, tried your solution but if i use the toJson directly on the sku it returns null:
`[ { '@type': 'd',
    'subcat.name': 'Beer',
    'CONCAT(sku.toJSON())': null,
    '@rid': { [String: '#-1:-1'] cluster: -1, position: -1 },
    '@version': 0 }`

If I use the method on the concat e.g.: `CONCAT(sku).toJson`

i get the message: `{"message": "expression item 'sku' cannot be resolved because current record is NULL\r\n\tDB name=\"VR3D\"",}`